# What is the name of this sequence generation problem? Any comments?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sequence

I need to iterate over an ordered sequence that is defined by an array of numbers *a*<sub>*i*</sub>, *i* = 1..*n*, where *n* is the length of each sequence element, and each *a*<sub>*i*</sub> specifies the max number of possible values at position *i* in the output sequence.

Example:

- a = {10,10,10}
  Sequence: `000`, `001`, `002`, ... `999` (the decimal numbers from `000` to `999`)
- a = (2,3,2}
  Sequence: `000`, `001`, `010`, `011`, `020`, `021`, `100`, `101`, `110`, `111`, `120`, `121`

(Note: I don't just need to print the sequence, but I need to iterate over its elements, where each element is an array, e.g. {1,2,1}.)

Before I implement this, I wanted to ask if anyone has any comments? Maybe this is a known problem (name?), and there is already code available, or it reduces to some other well-known problem? It does have similarities to the permutation problem.

Comment: Could you explain your question further? Is {10,10,10} supposed to output numbers from 000 to 999?

Comment: {10,10,10} gives you an iterator, which ranges over the elements {0,0,0}, {0,0,1}, {0,0,2}, ..., {9,9,9}. (Each element is an array.)

Answer (score 7):

This is a [**Cartesian product**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

In Python, [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) produces such lists of tuples.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(*map(range, [2, 3, 2])))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1),
 (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1)]
```

In other languages, it's easy to create a Cartesian product using nested loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
            cout << i << j << k << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the name and python code. Of course, for other languages, you cannot just use nested loops because it has to work for all $n$, not just for $n=3$, so I guess recursion has to be used instead.

Comment: @Frank Right. The recursion is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of the sequences are listed in the lexographic order. Also see [this](http://wordaligned.org/articles/next-permutation) (a different but related problem).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# (linq) and the number of factors in the cartesian product is static, then it can also be quite elgantly expressed

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> firstFactor = Enumerable.Range(0, 2);
        IEnumerable<int> secondFactor = Enumerable.Range(0, 3);

        var cartesianProd =
             from first in firstFactor
             from second in secondFactor
             select new { First = first, Second = second };

        foreach (var tuple in cartesianProd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1})", tuple.First, tuple.Second);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```